# AutoCompleteTextView adapter returning old values

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I implemented an AutoCompleteTextView where the data is updated from the server every time the user enters a new text input. It works well. However, every time I enter a new query, the previous results are displayed until the new result set is updated.

My guess is that it displays the currently queried results until the backend responds with the new search results. Is there a way to clear the current results?

**Activity code:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_test);

    actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actv);
    actv.setThreshold(1);
    actv.setAdapter(new SearchSuggestionsAdapter(this, actv.getText().toString()));
```

**Custom adapter:**

```
public class SearchSuggestionsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    List<String> types = new ArrayList<>();
    protected static final String TAG = "SuggestionAdapter";
    private List<String> suggestions;
    private Context context;

    public SearchSuggestionsAdapter(Activity context, String nameFilter) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        suggestions = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return suggestions.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return suggestions.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

                if (constraint != null) {

                    //Get new results from backend
                    //searchItemsFromServer is the method that returns the data
                    //new data is successfully sent. no problem there
                    List<String> new_suggestions = searchItemsFromServer(constraint.toString());
                    suggestions.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < new_suggestions.size(); i++) {
                        suggestions.add(new_suggestions.get(i));
                    }

                    filterResults.values = suggestions;
                    filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint,
                                          FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return myFilter;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Clear adapter old values

Comment: You have to cear your adapter and list old values as soon as your autocomplete text view value is empty or "". Add a Textwatcher in your autocompletetextview. then autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener and onTextchanged method compare with empty value and clear

Comment: I tried that with `adapter.clear()`. No change. Is that what you mean? @kapsym

Comment: So you already added a textwatcher for it to determine when to clear it?

Comment: @kapsym I tried that out before by adding a text watcher in the activity after setting the adapter. Can you show me your implementation suggestion?

Comment: do not add any `TextWatcher` the way you are doing now is ok, you only need to use a different `List` inside your `Filter` - see how it is done in `ArrayAdapter`: `final ArrayList<T> newValues = new ArrayList<>(`

Comment: @pskink Can you point out the change in relation to my code please?

Comment: @RickGrimesTheCoder did you call notifyDataSetChanged() after clear() ?

Comment: @andrei No I didn't

Comment: btw making a custom `Filter`s is a dirty job with no fun - see how easily you can do that with `FilterQueryProvider`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830

Comment: @pskink In that link you provided, what is `from` and `to` in the line: `    SimpleCursorAdapter a = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null, from, to, 0);`

Comment: Can you add that as an answer in relation to my code please? @pskink

Comment: run this code, then make it simpler - by removing the second `TextView` - i assume you are using just one `TextView` in your adapter

Comment: @pskink Haha sorry I am confused. Not sure what you mean

Comment: did you run it? does it work? if so, just implement *your* `runQuery` method - this is the place where you call your web API

Comment: What's `from` and `to` in `SimpleCursorAdapter` in relation to my implementation? @pskink

Comment: from = {"suggestion"}; to = {android.R.id.text1};

Comment: and: String[] columnNames = { BaseColumns._ID, "suggestion" };

Comment: I don't have anything named `suggestion`. Do you mean the list named `suggestions`? @pskink

Comment: this is a column name - name it foo, bar, suggestion, whatewver - did you run that code?

Comment: Yep, same output. No change @pskink

Comment: try actv.setAdapter(null);  right before     actv.setAdapter(new SearchSuggestionsAdapter(this, actv.getText().toString()));

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to your activity to this

```
SearchSuggestionsAdapter searchSuggestionsAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_test);

    searchSuggestionsAdapter = new SearchSuggestionsAdapter(this, actv.getText().toString());
    actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actv);
    actv.setThreshold(1);
    actv.setAdapter(searchSuggestionsAdapter);
    actv.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            if(!hasFocus){
              searchSuggestionsAdapter.clear();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Add the following code to your SearchSuggestionsAdapter

```
/**
 * Create list and notify recycler view
 */
public void clear() {
    if (suggestions != null) {
        suggestions.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 actv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                suggestionAdapter.clear;
            }
        });
```

When user click on autocomplete remove the old adapter. But for this you need to define suggesstionAdapter first. and every time update this adapter and set it to autocomplete

Comment: What if the user clicks on it once to get focus and then doesn't click again? This would only be limited to a click

Comment: So maybe using act.setOnFocusChangeListener  instead of onClickListener ?

Comment: I actually tried this with a text watcher. So every time a new character is entered, the adapter is cleared. The issue persists. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: In your textwatcher onTextChanged method just check if your string is empty before firing clear otherwise dont clear as it would be a part of continued search

Answer (score 0):

Clear suggestion before filtering. Call `adapter.clear();`

Add new method in adapter

```
public void clear() {
        suggestions.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Where would this be called from?

Comment: auto complete textchange listener

Comment: or on top of performFiltering

Comment: I appreciate the answer but it didn't work unfortunately. The old results are still displayed